# Open Root File Using Other Users ".bashrc -> .profile"

Tags: linux

If I have access to `.bashrc -> .profile` for *another* user which is owned by `root` with `lrwxrwxrwx` permissions

How could I capture `/root/flag.txt`? It's a Live CD.

Thanks

Comment: This is obviously a CTF exercise. You include some VERY important details in your comments below that you need to edit into to your question.

Comment: There are tons of things the designer of the CTF might have expected. There are known vulnerabilities in symlinks in some kernel versions. We don't know what else the fake system and fake processes do. We would need a lot more context.

Answer (score 3):

Let me make sure I understand the question properly: if you have *write* access to another user's `.bashrc` and/or `.profile` then you can plant any arbitrary code to be executed by them the next time they launch a shell / login, right? So why not add the following line to `.bashrc` / `.profile`

```
cp /root/flag.txt /home/<your_user>
```

or if you want to leave less of a paper trail:

```
chmod o+rw /root/flag.txt
```

Comment: I should be more clear - it's a Live CD I'm on as it's a test, so another user won't login. I was thinking of symlinking my bashrc to their profile... but is that too stupid?

Comment: hmm, I don't know then. The point is that the code has to be executed _by their user_, right?

Comment: @pee2pee Without knowing the ins and outs of this particular CTF, this is the generic answer.